# Good practices: to use a loop/while inside a view or to use them inside the controller but put HTML in the controller?

Tags: model-view-controller

My work colleague says is **bad practice to put logic in the views (while/loop)**, so hes making me use them in the controller to render the contents of a HTML table, but I think is even worse practice to **put HTML in the controller**, please need advice on what is the best practice? (if you have links that state why pick one from the other, really appreciate it)

**Approach 1:** No logic in the view, but a lot of HTML in the controller

**Controller**

```
<?php
//build a string in the controller with the HTML and send it to the view
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $users_print .= '
<tr>
    <td>' . $user['username'] . '</td>
    <td>' . $user['name'] . '</td>
</tr>
'; 
?>
```

**View** (just print the string with the HTML that was built in the controller)

```
        <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <?= $users_print; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Approach 2:** Do the loop in the view, no HTML in the controller but you need to use a loop/while in the view

**View**

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
foreach ($users as $user) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $user['username']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $user['name']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
} 
?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll go ahead with the second approach. In my opinion (in addition to what you say) you're not doing any "logic" in your view, since you're outputting the information as you received it.

Answer (score 0):

not sure If I help you, but I think, it's a matter of taste.

I rather do loops in views, so the controller and model do not include any "designed output". Controller or Model should not care about design. If someone will change/design your output code, he/she should not search in controllers or models - only in views. Designers should not edit controllers or models, only views.

But important is, to stand with the rule you set in whole code.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display an unknown number of elements, then loops in views are usually acceptable. As is very light branching - mainly to determine whether or not some part of the view should or should not be visible.

What you're not supposed to have in the view is "business logic." Not a very exact category, but basically you shouldn't, say, compute which values to display. But it's usually impractical for the view to have no dynamism at all. (Unless the view technology was explicitly designed to have non-imperative support for, at least, repeated and optional elements, but this is more common in component-oriented frameworks like Wicket or ASP.NET Web Forms, not in MVC. There's certainly no such thing in raw PHP.)

Ideally, it should be feasible to display the output of a controller using different kinds of view - e.g. a view that returns JSON to an app instead of HTML. If you assemble chunks of HTML in your controller, that becomes impossible, or you'd have to duplicate your controllers.